# Django dynamic links

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django so this could be a stupid question, however I'm struggling to find an answer searching Goolge. my question is as follows...

In other languages when creating links within HTML pages you have something like a buildURL(page) function that creates a dynamic link i.e.

```
<a herf="buildURL(pageName,queryObjects) >link</a>
```

This would generate the URL with parameters.

Is there a function in Django that builds URLs in the correct format i.e. generate a fully-qualified URL to a Django page with parameters?

Comment: This question is too broad. Narrow it down.

Comment: it is still too broad, are you talking about this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url  ? or about this:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls   ?

Comment: @danihp yes thats looks promising. hard to find when your don't know what its called. I want to generate a fully qualified URL to a Django page with parameters in my links.

Comment: @danihp https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls this is what I need cool!

Comment: Ok, I write an answer explaining this comment.

Comment: There is a template url tag. {% url 'path.to.some_view' arg1=v1 arg2=v2 %}. This won't add variables to the query string but it will add variables to the url which is the django way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your templates, you never should hard write url view. Instead of this, a good practice is to named each url and reference this name in templates.

To name a url:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #...
    url(r'^article/(\d+)/$', 'news.views.article', name='article_by_id'),
    #...
)
```

To reference url in template:

```
<ul>
{% for article in articles %}
<li><a href="{% url article_by_id article.pk %}">Article {{article.name}} </a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Learn more in [URL Distpatchar django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

from what I see in the django documentation it should be

```
<ul>
{% for article in articles %}
<li><a href="{% url 'article_by_id' article.pk %}">Article {{article.name}} </a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

i.e. 'article_by_id' instead of article_by_id. This works for me